# HP 1940 LCD not recognize on my ubuntu

Tags: 12.10, multiple-monitors

I use dual screen from my laptop to 19" HP 1940 LCD screen.

However ubuntu only recognized it as unknown monitor with very low resolution 1024x768 unable to reach the maximum resolution the screen can give to 1280x1024.

does anyone know how to play around with this issue?

My ubuntu is 12.10-64

Answer (score 1):

```
     You might try this I am not sure if it will work or not. I had issues like this as well with a 22 inch Curtis TV / Monitor, I used the following to fix my resolution issue and the monitor not being recognized by Ubuntu.
```

This may not work but it's worth a shot.

[Resolution / Monitor Fix](https://superuser.com/questions/311378/how-to-get-a-higher-resolution-on-ubuntu-11-04-using-an-intel-chipset)

Comment: I found it a litle bit flickr by the way...

Comment: update: after noticeable flickering.. now my HP LCD 1940 screen is smoked!.   I'm afraid the fix caused this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that I am connected to my second monitor through D-Link KVM switch and this is why my Ubuntu only recognize it as unknown monitor with low resolution 1024x768 and small flickering!

when I attached directly the second monitor to my laptop's VGA port, Ubuntu recognized it as HP monitor and gives the correct resolution which is 1280x1024 without flickering experience

Thank you!